# accidentally upgraded conda in wrong environment now wrong `base` of conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

While upgrading conda

`conda update -n base conda` (probably I did sth wrong in this step)

Somehow conda put my current environment as base.
Instead of just upgrading base.

Now, all my environment names are lost.

```
$ conda env list

# conda environments:
#
                         /home/user/.local/share/r-miniconda
                         /home/user/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
                         /home/user/miniconda3
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/homer
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/keras
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/keras-gpu
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/keras-new
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/magenta
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/multiqc
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/my_java18
base                  *  /home/user/miniconda3/envs/newR         # env `newR` is set as base
                         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/oldR
```

Please:
How can I get the names back or recreate the names and put the base correctly back?

Answer (score 0):

After trying long and googling long I gave up to find a regular solution.
After trying around and thinking I found only this hack:

Only a new installation of conda helps.
But to save time and reuse as much as possible, rename the miniconda3 folder

```
$ mv ~/miniconda3 ~/minconda3_old
$ mv ~/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh ~/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64_orig.sh
```

Then, reinstall conda (I use bash on ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Now conda is installed.
To copy my old `keras-new` environment, I do following:

```
$ conda create --name keras-new # create in the new miniconda a new env

orig_env=/media/daten/arnold/josephus/miniconda3/envs/keras-new
clone_env=/home/josephus/miniconda3/envs/keras-new
cp -r $orig_env/ $clone_env/
```

Now, I can use the old `keras-new` environment exactly as I did like before!